# "speak to me" vs "speak over me"

Tags: grammar

Which one would be correct to use?

> speak **to** me

or

> speak **over** me

I was listening a conversation and in that a person said

> Now you will not speak **over** me in an angry way

So could I use **"to"** instead of **"over"** here?

Answer (score 2):

"Speak **to** someone" simply means to speak to the other person. You can speak to someone nicely, or you can speak to someone harshly.

"Speak **over** someone" means to try to talk louder than the other person, so that your words can be heard over their words. It's generally rude behavior, and may involve interrupting the other person. When two people are trying to speak over each other, the conversation will usually get progressively louder and less civil in tone.

The two phrases are not interchangeable in most contexts, even though when you are speaking *over* someone, you also are speaking *to* that person – but not in a courteous way.

In this context, *over* means roughly "more than" in regards to the volume of noise. A similar way to use *over* might be:

> *We couldn't hear the birds over the traffic*.

That sentence isn't meant to refer to birds flying above the traffic; instead, it's talking about how the noise from the traffic is drowning out the songs from the birds.

Answer (score 0):

Speak to (with) me.

Speak over me.

There's nothing wrong with the construction of these sentences grammatically.  However, they differ in their sense.

You say "speak to me" when you want your interlocutor to talk to you/to have conversation with you.

"To speak over" carries a derogatory sense. If you speak over someone, it means that you interrupt someone while they speak. So you say "Don't speak over me", not "speak over me".